# How can upload large files to the Horton work Sandbox HDP 2.6.5

Tags: hadoop, hive, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari, hortonworks-sandbox

Is there any solution dor the error "request Entity Too large"
When try to upload file the size more than 200Mb using
Hortonworks Sandbox 2.6.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, never use a UI tool to upload data to HDFS (Ambari, HUE, etc).

SCP files from your host into the Sandbox (or mount a shared volume), then use `hdfs put` CLI commands.